# guillaumejuvenet - how this site is built ? / SVG path / self drawing

Tags: css, svg, path, automation, draw

http://www.guillaumejuvenet.com/
I'am impressed how this guy made his portfolio. Can anyone tell me how it is working?

I tried to make the path in illustrator and start draw it using stroke in CSS.
Everything  works but I'am still far, far away from similar effect.

Here is the way that I used for it.

```css
body {
  background-color: #a3d5d3;
}

#check path{
  stroke: red;
  stroke-width: 0.5px;
  stroke-dasharray: 116px; /* stroke-dasharray: 10px 5px;  linia obrysowania*/
  stroke-dashoffset: -116px; /*gdzie zaczynaja sie linie*/
  fill: transparent;
  transition: stroke-dashoffset 0.6s linear 0.5s, fill 1s ease;
  
}
#check.checked path {
  fill: #fff;
  stroke-dashoffset: 0px;
  transition: stroke-dashoffset 0.8s linear, fill 2s ease 0.7s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app ng-init="checked = false">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="200px" height="200px" viewBox="0 0 30 29" id="check" ng-class="checked ? 'checked' : ''">
 <path style="stroke-dashoffset: {{range}}px" fill="#fff" d="M1.609,0.008c0.013,0.129,0.023,0.248,0.033,0.367
  c0.103,1.153,0.203,2.307,0.307,3.459c0.132,1.465,0.265,2.933,0.395,4.397c0.11,1.232,0.219,2.467,0.328,3.7
  c0.124,1.389,0.249,2.777,0.373,4.167c0.109,1.23,0.218,2.467,0.328,3.699c0.134,1.502,0.27,3.002,0.398,4.504
  c0.008,0.098,0.039,0.139,0.135,0.164c3.177,0.896,6.352,1.793,9.525,2.688c0.08,0.021,0.176,0.021,0.256,0
  c3.187-0.895,6.373-1.789,9.56-2.682c0.109-0.031,0.143-0.078,0.15-0.186c0.067-0.838,0.146-1.674,0.219-2.51
  c0.082-0.922,0.166-1.846,0.248-2.77c0.074-0.826,0.146-1.65,0.221-2.477c0.084-0.924,0.166-1.848,0.248-2.771
  c0.072-0.825,0.146-1.649,0.221-2.476c0.082-0.92,0.164-1.84,0.246-2.76c0.074-0.828,0.146-1.656,0.223-2.486
  c0.082-0.92,0.164-1.84,0.246-2.76c0.074-0.838,0.148-1.678,0.228-2.517c0.021-0.25,0.042-0.502,0.065-0.76
  C17.571,0.008,9.6,0.008,1.609,0.008z M20.831,7.965c-3.82,0-7.638,0-11.47,0c0.09,1.033,0.179,2.056,0.267,3.082
  c3.649,0,7.287,0,10.938,0c-0.026,0.217-0.061,0.422-0.08,0.629c-0.051,0.521-0.1,1.043-0.146,1.562
  c-0.084,0.943-0.166,1.892-0.248,2.835c-0.071,0.848-0.146,1.691-0.221,2.539c-0.047,0.535-0.101,1.07-0.146,1.604
  c-0.008,0.084-0.062,0.086-0.11,0.102c-1.294,0.355-2.585,0.713-3.878,1.066c-0.709,0.197-1.416,0.396-2.126,0.592
  c-0.032,0.01-0.076,0.004-0.11-0.008c-2.006-0.551-4.011-1.104-6.015-1.652c-0.092-0.023-0.094-0.08-0.1-0.146
  c-0.051-0.645-0.102-1.283-0.15-1.927c-0.067-0.864-0.135-1.729-0.203-2.595c-0.002-0.021-0.002-0.049-0.004-0.08
  c0.99,0,1.978,0,2.971,0c0.025,0.281,0.052,0.563,0.076,0.838c0.044,0.49,0.088,0.98,0.13,1.473
  c0.004,0.057,0.021,0.078,0.075,0.094c1.076,0.287,2.15,0.578,3.228,0.867c0.038,0.012,0.084,0.006,0.123-0.004
  c1.063-0.285,2.123-0.574,3.188-0.855c0.063-0.02,0.092-0.049,0.098-0.113c0.117-1.254,0.236-2.51,0.357-3.764
  c0-0.004-0.002-0.008-0.004-0.022c-3.463,0-6.929,0-10.401,0C6.596,11.049,6.326,8.029,6.055,5c5.025,0,10.028,0,15.057,0
  C21.021,5.988,20.925,6.971,20.831,7.965z"/>
  </svg>
  <button ng-click="checked = !checked">Toggle</button>
</div>
```

Any tips?

Comment: what do you currently have?, i couldn't access your codepen - This guy is using SVG images. https://css-tricks.com/using-svg/

Comment: snippet is working now. His method to draw shapes is different. And looks much better.

Comment: It looks like he builds it that way but then replaces it with an image file at the end, so it will look smoother

Comment: I will try to replace it on the end with slow opacity transition. 
But how is hi able to draw it from file? is no SVG path's in HTML.

Comment: Have you tried emailing him from his website, He might give you some pointers.

Comment: Maybe you have right, I will ask him ;)